# Java program to print a string pattern

Tags: java, string

if the input string is
"ADMINISTRATIONS"
the pattern should be like this
A
DM
INI
STRA
TIONS

The last row should be completely filled

if the input string is "COMPUTER"
the pattern should be like this
C
OM
PUT
ER**

the incomplete last row should be filled with *

i have got the pattern but couldnt print the stars.

```
    int k=0;
    String str = "computer";
    String[] s=str.split("\\B");
    for(int i=0; i<s.length;i++){
        for(int j=0; j<i;j++){
            if(k<s.length){
        System.out.println(s[k]);
        k++;
            }
    }
        System.out.println();
```

Help me to solve this.

Comment: Hey new user! Stack overflow is not for homework questions.

Comment: Show what you've got so far and explain with what you're struggeling.

Comment: @Swordfish i posted what i have done

Comment: what should happen if `k` is not less than then `s.length`?

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger if k is greater than s.length, it is error. Array Index out of bounds exception.

Comment: but think what the program should do, since there are no more chars in the array (just  a hint, print something else)

Comment: in "computer" the last row will contain "e" and "r" only.

Comment: if the last row is incomplete the remaining spaces should be filled with *

Comment: then, if not `k < s.length` print a `*` to fill the rest of the line

Comment: for example, if "Company" is the given string, the pattern should be  c  om  pan  y***

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger if i print * for that condition the number of rows will be 8

Comment: for k<s.length condition, c  om  put  er**  *****  ******  *******  ********  the output wil be like this

Comment: `if (k < s.length) { System.out.print(s[k++]); } else { System.out.print("*"); }` as I wrote before: what to do if **not** `k < s.length`, that is, when k is >= s.length, that is, the rest **after** the array's length

Comment: k>=s.length will result in infinite loop

Comment: if that part is working, exit the first loop when reaching the end of the array (could use some mathematics, or just test k against s.length again)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Written when no code was provided - earlier it was tagged under **C**.

It is simple recursive to print string in the way described in the problem statement. Here is a **C** equivalent code to do this (as this question has been tagged in **Java** as well):

```
  #include<stdio.h>

  int i=1;

  void fun(char c[])
  {
      int j=0;

      while((j<i)&&(c[j]))
      {
          printf("%c",c[j++]);
      }
      while((c[j]=='\0')&&(j<i))
      {
          printf("*");
          ++j;
      }

      ++i;
      if(c[j])
      {
          printf(" ");
          fun(c+j);
      }
  }

  int main(void)
  {
      char c[]="computer";
      fun(c);
      return 0;
  }
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
 c om put er**
```

If you want to replace the `\0` check then you can use the length of string as a check as I am not aware if null termination is there in Java.

Comment: No, the 4th row should be er**, since it is incomplete.

Comment: @SelvaKumar Check now.

Comment: @SelvaKumar Then you can check this:https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Java version, since comments are not appropriate for code:

```
String str = "computer";
int k = 0;
for (int i=0; k<str.length(); i++) {  // note: condition using k
    for (int j=0; j<i; j++) {
        if (k < str.length()) {
            System.out.print(str.charAt(k++));
        } else {
            System.out.print("*");  // after the end of the array
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

<sup>not tested, just an idea</sup>

Notes: there is no need to use `split` since we want each character of the string - we can use `charAt` (or `toCharArray`). Using `print` instead of `println` to not change lines.

Comment: I hope now it is easier to understand what I meant by what to do when not `k < str.length` - the line in the `else` block